# What's the best way to create a waiting page using the struts framework

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, struts, struts-1

I have a page which requires retrieving results from a service, and that takes a long time. In between this page and the previous, I would like a "please wait, loading" page. What's the best way of doing this. Preferably with struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [struts-1-solutions](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/struts-1-solutions.html) and then [Execute and Wait Interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html)

hopes that helps

Answer (score 1):

I use this http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ jquery resource for achieve your requirement.
In this overlay you can build a progress bar which frequenlty ask the server the operation status.